# Splitting a string of integers with spaces without converting to a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I need a code that takes an integer and then prints out the string of numbers with the certain range.

For example:

n = 11

1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4

n = 7

1 2 2 3 3 3 4

```
a = []
n = int(input())
if n == 0:
    print(n)
for i in range(int(n) + 1):
    a += [i] * i
a = ' '.join(map(str, a))
print(a[:n])
```

This does the job but it counts spaces as characters, so I tried to convert it to an int

```
n = int(n)
print(' '.join(a[:n]))
```

But when the n >= 47, it starts to print out 10 as 1 0 which is incorrect

I also tried this code

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    b = (str(i) * i)
    print(b, end = ' ')
```

But I don't understand how to separate the b with spaces **without** converting the string to a list and printing it in one line either.
I am not sure if it is even possible.

Comment: Why specifically don't you want to create a list?

Comment: Because this is an exercise from online course, and I became curious as to why it is not possible to split a string without converting it to a list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
# initialize variables:
number = 11
counter = 0

for i in range(number):

    for j in range(i):

        # print number:
        print('%d ' %i, end='')

        # increment counter (tracks how many numbres to print):
        counter += 1

        # exit inner loop if counter reaches number:    
        if counter >= number-1: break

    # exit outer loop if counter reaches number:
    if counter >= number-1: break
```

Output:

```
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine thank you, but I wanted to know why I couldnt use my almost ready solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). Generators, `chain`, `repeat` and `islice` are all lazily evaluated, so this uses O(1) space.

```py
>>> n = 7
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat, islice
>>> gen = chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, i) for i in range(1, n+1))
>>> for i in islice(gen, n):
...     print(i, end=' ')
... 
1 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

Comment: It was recomended for me to solve this problem using only built-in functions, but thanks for the answer anyway!
Also, for some reason your code prints different output for me
When n = 4 it prints 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 instead of 1 2 2 3 3 3 4

Comment: `itertools` is a built-in module.

Comment: @MarkoPolo `itertools` is a part of python stdlib.

Comment: @MarkoPolo The correct output for `n = 4` should be `1 2 2 3` as far as I understand the question, and that's what this solution prints. It will print what you showed if you write `for i in gen:` without using `islice`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems simple. But this does solve the problem?

```
>>> for i in t:
...     if i!=" ": print i
...
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

or even string replace like,

```
print t.replace(" ","\n")
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```